# Why did my apple cider vinegar hiss when I opened it?

Tags: food-safety, vinegar

I opened a bottle of apple cider vinegar and it made a hissing sound when I opened it (like beer). I thought it was okay and poured it on my salad but it did smell a bit yeasty. I put the salad in the fridge and didn't eat it. I called the company and they said that that was not normal and to take it back. My question is what do I do with the salad? Okay to handle/compost? Would the presence of yeast change the ph level to non-acid levels? Or would it be like beer?